# Servicestack does not deserialize my json string into a c# class

Tags: c#, json, jquery, servicestack

I am sending a cross domain jquery ajax request to our server:

```
$.ajax({
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
},
data: data,
type: "GET",
url: requestUrl,
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
async: true,                      
dataType: 'json',
crossDomain: true
};
```

The data object sent has this format:

```
var data = {
    Customer: { id: 1 },
    Order: { id: 1 }
};
```

data is converted with JSON.stringify(data) and sent to the server.

On the Server I have this request object:

```
public class RequestObject
{
   public CustomerRef Customer { get; set; }
   public OrderRef Order { get; set; }
}
```

both objects has still an id property.

When I debug on server side the request object is created but both properties Customer and Order are null.

I am requesting data (GET) with parameters in the data object.

Thats the way my sent url looks like:

```
http://localhost:82/json/reply/MyService?{%22Customer%22:{%22id%22:1},%22Order%22:{%22id%22:1}}
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, the solution was to set the contentType property in the .ajax call to "application/json". After I did this, all serialization worked great.

Here is my test code:

```
var dataObject = {RequestString: "hello service!", RequestDetails: {ClientName: "val1", ClientGroupID: "val2"}, Arguments: {dict1: {test1: "test1", test2: "test2"}}};

var dataString = JSON.stringify(dataObject);

var request = $.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:1337/testws",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",        
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function (d) {
    $("#result-div").text(JSON.stringify(d));
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("web call failed! d" + textStatus);
}
});
```

Comment: I used this too just did not post it. The problems was in the cross domain etc... we made the service RESTfull now and it works.